# Immutable objects in C++11 and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm trying to create an immutable class in C++11, which (for convenience) provides methods that modify the current state. To satisfy the immutable contract, these methods must return a new instance with the updated contents.

In the following snippet, `ImmutableObject::setA()` and `ImmutableObject::setB()` update the `a` and `b` attributes in a new instance of `ImmutableObject` created via a copy constructor and return it. The method `print()` just displays the content.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ImmutableObject().setA(1).setB(2).print();
    return 0;
}
```

(An implementation of `ImmutableObject` is provided below.)

Implementing this naively using C++03 causes an unnecessary copies to be created.

I am wondering if C++11 move semantics can be used to exploit the fact that `ImmutableObject()` and the return value of `setA()` are just temporary copies that could be directly updated.

I already added a rvalue copy and assignment constructor in the code below, but it does not look like it's working. When running the program, I get

```
In constructor
In copy constructor
In copy constructor
a=1, b=2
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ImmutableObject {
public:
    ImmutableObject() { 
        std::cout << "In constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ImmutableObject(const ImmutableObject &obj) : a(obj.a), b(obj.b) {
        std::cout << "In copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ImmutableObject(ImmutableObject&& other) {
        std::cout << "In move constructor" << std::endl;
        a = other.a;
        b = other.b;
    }

    ImmutableObject &operator=(ImmutableObject&& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            a = other.a;
            b = other.b;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ImmutableObject setA(int value) {
        ImmutableObject result(*this);
        result.a = value;
        return result;
    }

    ImmutableObject setB(int value) {
        ImmutableObject result(*this);
        result.b = value;
        return result;
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << "a=" << a << ", b=" << b << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Comment: @Deduplicator: The attribute assignments in `setA()` etc don't work in this case. If I understand you correctly though, you're suggesting to make the immutable nature more explicit to the compiler's optimizer? I was hoping for something more language-specific that doesn't depend on what the compiler's optimizer may or may not do.

Comment: Anyway, why does just using a `const` object not serve?

Comment: In each of those member functions, `*this` is an lvalue, hence the copy. In my opinion, you should add rvalue-ref-qualifiers and then move `*this`, e.g. `ImmutableObject setA(int value) && { ImmutableObject result(std::move(*this)); result.a = value; return result; }` (Another question is if that should be your basic implementation, or if you first design a "MutableObject" and then add "immutability" on top of it.)

Comment: @Deduplicator, your suggestion would allow the copies in the return value to become moves, but that would still be suboptimial, because each `setA` and `setB` function returns a temporary, which could be moved from. dyp's suggestion solves that problem, so that when you call a function on an rvalue it moves from `*this`

Comment: @dyp: I think that's what I was looking for! Do you want to turn that into an answer?